# Linq to SQL Impersonation

Tags: iis, linq-to-sql, impersonation, kerberos

I have an ASP.MVC 3.0 application. My solution is containing a Linq to SQL project (.dbml). I0ve made the choice to put it in a different project and not in the web application project. I also have another project which connect "mannually" to the database (DAL). 
I deploy my application on a webserver, activate the impersonation and the Kerberos delegation. Impersonation for the DAL is working fine, but for an unknown reason the Linq to SQL impersonation is not working. Do I miss something?
Here is the web.config form the web application:

```
 <identity impersonate="true"/>
```

Here is the app.config from the Linq to SQl project:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="testConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Integrated Security=True;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Do I miss something in the server configuration, or in the delegation?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the app.config from the Linq to SQl my project:

`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString=
"server=server name or ip addrress;database=dbname;uid=id;pwd=pass"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`